# How to configure Plesk to use nginx for sub-domains?

Tags: nginx

I've tried to setup nginx on my brand new linux-server together with Plesk 10.3 (latest) and created a new nginx subdomain for port 8226 - how can I configure Plesk to use nginx as a server for my subdomain created in Plesk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a so called **"reversed proxy"**. You do not need to create another subdomain in your [Plesk-Panel](http://www.parallels.com).

Just tell your apache, to proxy all requests from sub.mydomain.com to your predefined nginx-port (8226).

Create a new file `nginx.conf` and save it under `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`

```
<VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:80>

ServerName "sub.mydomain.com:80"
UseCanonicalName Off
ServerAlias  "sub.mydomain.com"

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://sub.mydomain.com:8226/
ProxyPassReverse / http://sub.mydomain.com:8226/
ServerName sub.mydomain.com

</VirtualHost>
```

Reload apache `service httpd reload`

For further questions, I advise you to read the official [Apache Virtual Host Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/vhosts/).